# How can there be a quote for EUR/USD from 1980s?

Tags: currency, eur-euro, usd-us-dollar

As far as I know, the euro currency was introduced some time in the late 1990s, many countries adopting it at the beginning of the 21st century. However, I've run into charts depicting EUR vs. USD starting from as early as the 1980s. Why is this? How can there be a currency exchange rate EUR/USD before the birth of the euro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably those charts substitute the [European Currency Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Currency_Unit)/USD exchange rates for quotes between ~1979-1999.