# What is the data before 1999 for EUR to USD on Google?

Tags: european-union, eur-euro

If you search `eur to usd` on Google, you'll see a chart.

The chart starts from 198x as below:

[image]

However, on this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_euro). It says

> The euro came into existence on 1 January 1999

Is it a Google mistake? What does the data before 1999 mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can there be a quote for EUR/USD from 1980s?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/74761/how-can-there-be-a-quote-for-eur-usd-from-1980s)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The same wiki page says EUR replaced [ECU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Currency_Unit) with 1:1 rate. So history before 1999 likely represents ECU/USD rate.

However, I'm not sure why is starts in 1982 then, as ECU was introduced in 1979.

Comment: Looks like all their data goes back to 16 Apr 1982, e.g. GBP/USD has the same starting point.